# "Incorrect Padding" error when trying to do an update mutation

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I have a graphql function to update an existing model. I keep getting an error message with "incorrect padding." I'm not sure what is happening.

Here is the mutation:

```
mutation {
  updateProject(projectData: {id: "1" name:"updated"}) {
    project {
      name
    }
    ok
  }
}
```

I similarly used a create mutation that works perfectly fine:

```
 mutation {
  createProject(projectData: {name:"Test2"}) {
    project {
      name
    }
    ok
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/14#issuecomment-155726280

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!